# Wagtail: indexing many-to-many relationships with reverse accessors in Elasticsearch 5

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, many-to-many, wagtail

I am unable to get Elasticsearch, through Wagtail's `update_index` command, to index a many-to-many relationship with a reverse accessor.

To demonstrate the problem, consider the models available here: https://bpaste.net/show/6b1477ff0971
(This is a minimal working example that shows both working and non-working indexing for two many-to-many relationships).

This is using Wagtail 1.8.1, Elasticsearch 5.1.1, and elasticsearch-py 5.1.0.

Here, I make two attempts to index many-to-many relationships:

1. Tags: which have an explicit field in the `MyPage` model, and a `through` attribute for that field.
2. Categories: which are attached to `MyPage` in the `MyPageCategory` model using a `related_name='categories'` (no explicit field in `MyPage`). In the code above, I show three different attempts to capture the categories relationship in the `search_fields` of the `MyPage` model, none of which is successful.

There may be other differences between the way tags and categories are configured too that may be causing the problem.

**Problem**: Elasticsearch does not index the categories, but does index the tags:

```
"indexing_mypage__categories" : null,
"indexing_mypage__tags" : [
    {
        "name" : "tag2"
    }
],
```

**Question:** How can I get Elasticsearch to index the categories of `MyPage`? What should `MyPage.search_fields` look like?

The goal is to be able to search pages by their categories.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question 100% but I came across this question after having a similar issue. Here was my solution to indexing authors for a post and categories (I call them issues). This is taken from the wagtail [docs](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/topics/search/indexing.html).

```
search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
    index.SearchField('get_issues'),
    index.SearchField('get_columnists'),
]

def get_issues(self):
    # Get list of issues and concatenate them
    return '\n'.join(self.issues.all().values_list('issue', flat=True))

def get_columnists(self):
    # Get list of columnists
    return '\n'.join(self.columnists.all().values_list('name', flat=True))
```